# Most effective way to convert PrestaShop Theme from 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I have to upgrade my store, because my server won't support the PHP version required for PS 1.6 anymore.

From my research so far it looks as if PS 1.7 might as well be a completely different ecommerce platform when it comes to themes.

What's my best bet to convert my current, custom PS 1.6 theme and make it compatible with PS 1.7?

I don't wanna have to code the whole thing from scratch. I wanna be able to get at least 80 or 90% of the way there, and then fix the remaining glitches.

How can I make it so that the upgrade from PS 1.6 to 1.7 won't cost me several months of development work?

**Edit:**
The workaround solution is to *use ThirtyBees*. Details in my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this question was posted on Prestahop Forum as well I'll add here my reply there for future similar questions.

There is no conversion from a 1.6+ to a 1.7 theme or from 1.6+ to 1.7+ modules.

You need new theme and modules and that's it.

All you can upgrade are the Prestashop files and the database.

Comment: That's extremely frustrating... Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It is understandable to feel this way. It is not something the Prestashop or other platforms want too but every platform is based on many (opensource) libraries that other people maintain and once in a few years dramatic changes can appear forcing the platform to adapt. In this particular case PS decided to switch from an old code to a newer approach, use the Symfony framework (currently for the backoffice) etc. In the end it may have been a good decision since it is very hard to maintain and secure old legacy code. But of course it is extremely frustrating for the end users.

Answer (score 0):

> my server won't support the PHP version required for PS 1.6
>
> What's my best bet to convert my current, custom PS 1.6 theme
>
> I don't wanna have to code the whole thing from scratch. I wanna be
>   able to get at least 80 or 90% of the way there, and then fix the
>   remaining glitches.
>
> How can I make it so that the upgrade won't cost me
>   several months of development work?

The best solution for this, really, is to **USE THIRTYBEES**

ThirtyBees is a Prestashop fork, it was forked after 1.6, and is it's own platform.

The team over at Prestashop is making some massive changes to the Prestashop core, which removes lots of documented functionality. And as they slowly transition over, it's probably better to not rely on the architecture, if you're not able to constantly implement upgrades and changes.

Reference:

https://build.prestashop.com/news/prestashop-in-2019-and-beyond-part-2-pain-points/

https://thirtybees.com/

After trying to adapt my store to PS 1.7, which took 2 weeks and I hit roadblock after roadblock, I switched to Thirtybees. It took me 1 day to make the same progress that it took me 2 weeks on PS. I can see myself being done with this upgrade progress soon, and I can soon focus on more crucial business activities again.